# Где вариант "ответ-ссылка"?

Tags: дефект, тревоги

Куда в тревогах к ответу подевался вариант "ответ-ссылка"?

Comment: его вроде и не было в тревогах. Такой пункт был в вариантах в очереди проверки

Comment: Я тоже не помню, чтобы такой пункт был в тревогах. Для таких случаев обычно используют тревогу "не является ответом". А "ответ-ссылка" это результат проверки (в группе "рекомендовать удаление", кажется) с комментарием-подсказкой.

Comment: @D-side, _Для таких случаев обычно используют тревогу "не является ответом"_ - лучше с кастомным текстом

Comment: @Grundy с кастомным текстом можно только модератору отправить тревогу, не?

Comment: @D-side, ага :)

Comment: Ответ-ссылка это «не является ответом».

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как уже было справедливо замечено в комментариях к вопросу, в тревогах к ответу пункта, подобного "ответ-ссылка", никогда не было. Существующие пункты:

- спам
- невежливый или оскорбительный
- не является ответом
- необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством
- требуется вмешательство модератора

Вариант "Ссылка на ответ вместо самого ответа" присутствует в очереди проверок сообщений низкого качества. Данный вариант добавляет соответствующий комментарий к проверяемому ответу при голосовании за удаление.